# How to Create an APK in Android Studio?

Tags: apk

I want to make an APK in Android Studio but when I create it, it shows this error:

```
Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced same issue when creating signed apk from android studio. I just change little bit change on build.gradle file inside android {}

```
lintOptions {
  checkReleaseBuilds false
  abortOnError false
}
```